# Filters in cascade

Tags: filter, frequency, active-filter

Let´s say that in order to avoid having a filter of too large of a degree, I use multiple filters in cascade:

Low frequency gain of 8dB

Cut-off frequency of 4Hz

Chebyshev of order 2

Would the resulting filter still be considered a Chebyshev filter?

Would the cut-off frequency, peak frequency, etc still be the same as if we only had one Chebyshev filter?

Comment: The cut-off frequency is at the 3 dB point and if you use two identical cascaded filters at the previous cut-off frequency, the signal will be reduced by another 3 dB i.e. 6 dB. This means that the new cut-off frequency is different to the old cut-off frequency. Also, what do you mean by *peak frequency*?

Comment: The frequency where the resonance peak occurs.

Comment: What about if it can still be considered a Chebyshev filter?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.

Comment: It is a chebychev type filter only if the cascaded stages are specifically designed to work together to provide a chebychev type response as a whole. Otherwise it isn't.

Comment: Your question is poorly asked. Chebyshev is a type of filter with specific properties, There are many ways to build one.   When you use the term “order” , it means the same as “degree”, therefore in your specification you have defined the filter to have degree two.

Answer (score 2):

No, it will not be (as @Justme says in the comments). You are using the same kernel (filter), several times in cascade. That results in repeated convolution, which converges towards a Gaussian bell (for strictly increasing monotonic functions of attenuation, such as Butterworth). In this case, because of the ripple in the passband, you will have the same pole(s) over and over. The filter will only be Chebyshev (or whatever other kind) as long as it will be calculated to be as such. If you want to only consider each stage, separately, individually, then yes, you have multiple Chebyshev filters, but not together.

Here's an example of 4 cascaded 2nd order Chebyshev filters with 1dB ripple (black-blue-red-green), and their effects, compared to an 8th order one (pink):

[image: cascade]